# GWT application, Session doesnt expire - is this right?

Tags: session, gwt

I'm writing my first GWT application and i'm at the point of implementing sessions.

Currently i' generating a

```
HttpServletRequest request = getThreadLocalRequest();
HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession(true);
httpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(1000 * 60 * 2);//2min
```

and then verifying that the session is the same as the users via RPC call to server before displaying any screen

```
HttpServletRequest request = getThreadLocalRequest();
HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession(false);

if(user.getSessionId().equals(result.getSessionId()))
    //display screen
```

My question is concerning setMaxInactiveInterval(); the inactive timeout doesn't seem to work for me at all - the session doesnt expire on its own after two mins

Am i going about it the right way? Thanks.

p.s. i used this as a jump off: http://snipt.net/javagner/session-in-gwt/

Comment: i tried playing with the numbers i nsession timeout also, 1*60 etc

Comment: Is there any documentation for that code you link to? I would like to get a little more detail why this approach was choosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually there is this in the web.xml

```
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout> <!-- 30 minutes -->
  </session-config>
```

Comment: Ive still not fixed the problem but it seems that the web.xml configuration and setMaxInactiveInterval() method really are the two ways of configuring the session. It must be a problem with something else..

Answer (score 1):

```
httpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(1000 * 60 * 2);//2min
```

This is not 2 minutes, but rather 2000 minutes.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html

**javax.servlet.http.HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval)**

> Specifies the time, **in seconds**, between client requests before the
>   servlet container will invalidate this session.